# PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server.

Tags: selenium, yii, phpunit

I using PHPUnit and Selenium Server to testing Yii Application, but whenever i tried it always give me this error.

PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server.

i m using xp operating system. and i install PHPUnit_Selenium (1.0.1) and other software.actually i follow this bellow instruction to install these software so is it enough?
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/14995-wamp-netbeans-phpunit-selenium-yii/

i followed all instruction give in these page..

and i tried to test my simple helloworld yii application from command prompt
i attached the command prompt image..

http://s8.postimage.org/sh79ue68l/error.jpg

i m very new to this so plz give me step by step instruction.. plz help me..

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got Selenium server running?
You should have it installed or just run [Selenium Server Standalone](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list).

Look there:
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.1/en/selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you linked is for netbeans, if you run the test from inside netbeans it will automatically run selenium if you installed it correctly.

Alternatively you can download the jar file and run it directly, and then run your test from the commandline.

http://seleniumhq.org/download/

current version:
http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar

Comment: this jar file where i need to put ??
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\includes\PHPUnit-3.5.7\PHPUnit\Extensions\SeleniumTestCase
can i put inside this directory ??

Comment: if you're using the standalone it doesn't matter where you put it, you're running it independently, so you could even put it on your desktop and run it there.